# Output voltage drop LM358

Tags: amplifier, single-supply-op-amp, voltage-amplification

I am running a LM358 in a simple non-inverting amplification circuit. I am using the single rail supply option, grounding V- and applying 24V to V+. The input voltage is 4V and I want to amplify it as much as possible. With no load, I do get around 22V (more is probably possible), however, when I attach a load (a solenoid valve), the output voltage drops down to around 16V.  If I reduce the gain to output around 15V, it stays the same, with or without load attached. When I hook up the supply voltage directly to the solenoid valve, the voltage stays constant too. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How much current are you attempting to pull from the op-amp?  You may have to add an emitter-follower buffer stage between the output of the op-amp and the load.  Probably all you need is a single NPN transistor.

Comment: @DwayneReid The solenoid valve draws 75mA. Thanks for the tip, so something like this, to achieve low impedance? https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/transistor/transistor-common-collector-emitter-follower.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While different variants have different limits, the [LM358 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358b.pdf) shows the order of magnitude for maximum output current (just search the document for "output current") is generally a few tens of milliamps or less.  When you try to source or sink too much, weirdities like you're describing can happen.  Solenoids can take a lot of current.

If this is your problem, you will need to include some sort of driver to provide the necessary current.